# ExecuteTypedList error with Stored Procedure using Subsonic 3

Tags: asp.net, subsonic

In the code block below I am attempting to execute a Stored Procedure from Asp.net.

```
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("GetIDsWithinRadius");
sp.Command.AddParameter("ZipCode", 03461);
sp.Command.AddParameter("GivenMileRadius", 4);
List<DbData.User> users = sp.ExecuteTypedList<DbData.User>();
```

The last line of code that tries to load the return data into a typed list produces the following error at runtime. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to char is not allowed. 
Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generated code for DbData.User probably has the wrong data type for the `sql_variant` field being returned by your stored procedure.

Most likely, the `sql_variant` data type is mapped incorrectly (or not mapped explicitly) in your version of SubSonic. In the source that applies to your version, you could look to see what `sql_variant` is mapped to in the [GetDbType](https://github.com/joshrivers/SubSonic-3.0/blob/c8a7add431114f0382bdaa33f7aedbaab7d89ba7/SubSonic.Core/SQLGeneration/Schema/Sql2005Schema.cs) method.